# I add sql parameters but I get the error "not added"

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlclient

I get this error:

> Procedure or function 'GetCurrencyAtDate' expects parameter '@soruceCurrencyId', which was not supplied.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrencyAtDate]
    @soruceCurrencyId int,
    @targetCurrencyId int,
    @year int,
    @month int,
    @day int,
    @result decimal OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @targetDate DATETIME
    SET @targetDate = DATEADD(DAY, @day - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, @month - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0)))

    SELECT TOP 1 @result = Currency
    FROM KurTable
    WHERE SourceKur = @soruceCurrencyId
      AND TargetKur = @targetCurrencyId
      AND Date <= @targetDate
    ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, Date, @targetDate));
END
```

I am using Entity Framework Core and wrote command via `DbContext` functions:

```
using (var context = new EfDataContext())
{
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    var year = date.Year;
    var month = date.Month;
    var day = date.Day;

    var resultParameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@result",
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal,
                };

    var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "GetCurrencyAtDate";

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sourceCurrencyId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = sourceCurrency });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@targetCurrencyId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = targetCurrency });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@year", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = year });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@month", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = month });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = day });
    command.Parameters.Add(resultParameter);

    context.Database.OpenConnection();

    var result = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
    currencyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: In your Stored Procedure, the first argument name `@soruceCurrencyId` but not `@sourceCurrencyId`.

Comment: @YongShun ı tried many way to get result value but every time returns null. This time again null returned. This is another question

Comment: First, this isn't EF code, it's plain old ADO.NET. You're (mis)using DbContext just to get a SqlConnection. You definitely don't need EF for that. Second, you misspelled `sourceCurrencyId` as `soruceCurrencyId `. Finally, your code never checks the value of `resultParameter`. It tries to check a non-existent return value

Comment: @YongShun the code doesn't try to read the output parameter at all. It's trying to read any query results, but the stored procedure doesn't return any

Comment: You should able to get value via `currencyValue = resultParameter.Value;`

Comment: Both the code and the stored procedure need some *very serious cleaning up*. For starters, if you want to search by a date, pass a `date` parameter, not individual parts. The `targetDate` variable should be a parameter. `ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, Date, @targetDate))` makes no sense when you're searching for earlier dates. Just `ORDER BY Date` does the exact same thing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you mean this -> `var another = resultParameter.Value;
currencyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(another);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos order by date does not meet my needs, this procedure is used in other ways as well so procedure working well

Comment: @YongShun ok ı writed but returned empty array {}

Comment: Why do you make that incorrect assumption? What you wrote is the same thing only slower, because it can't use any indexes and will have to scan the *entire* table. `this procedure is used in other ways as well so procedure working well` definitely not. It's deeply broken. Why are date parts passed individually instead of a `date`  parameter? And even if there was a valid reason, why is `@targetDate` calculated like this instead of using `DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,@day)`? In fact, why use a stored procedure *at all* for such a simple query?

Comment: `returned empty array {}` ADO.NET doesn't return arrays at all. SQL Server itself doesn't have array types

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thus ı am junier and my company servers not properly installed. so we cant send DateTime value directly. I can not match date format db and app. So we found the solution like this. And you are right. Absolutelly nonsense this procedure

Comment: This has nothing to do with installations. Dates have no format, they're binary values. SQL Server has no arrays. If the `Date` is a `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` column, there's no format at all. If it's a text column, you have a very serious problem that needs fixing first.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can ı send an image of result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we are having problems with System.CultureInfo class both db server and app server. İnt values is going well but date and decimal values is broken

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://ibb.co/tPRrxkp

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for this line `DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,@day)`. I also don't do like this way because of you explained `scan entire table`. I want to find nearest date which ı give via `@year, @month, @day`. I found only this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with this code that would make it very slow even if it worked - it misuses EF Core only to execute ADO.NET code, it forgets to close the connection, the stored procedure itself is overcomplicated, and eg uses `ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, Date, @targetDate))` to do what `ORDER BY Date` would also do. The date is passed as parts then reconstructed in a complicated way instead of using `DATEFROMPARTS`

All of the options below can be used with a stored procedure but in this case, it's just not needed.

To actually get the latest exchange rate from a table all you'd need using eg [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to reduce the boilerplate would be this:

```
var sql=@" SELECT TOP 1 Currency
    FROM KurTable
    WHERE SourceKur = @fromCur
        AND TargetKur = @toCur
        AND Date <= @date
    ORDER BY Date DESC";

using (var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var rate=con.ExecuteScalar<decimal>(sql,new { 
        fromCur=sourceCurrency,
        toCur=targetCurrency,
        date=DateTime.Today
    });
}
```

That's all. Dapper will create a SqlCommand with parameters based on the anonymous type properties, using the same names and types, open the connection, execute the query, return the result *and* close the connection. It will also case the command and mappings so it doesn't have to rebuild it next time.

In this example the connection is created in a `using` block so it gets disposed once the block exits.

You can use a DbContext's connection directly if you want too.

```
var con=context.Database.GetDbConnection();
var rate=con.ExecuteScalar<decimal>(sql,new { 
        fromCur=sourceCurrency,
        toCur=targetCurrency,
        date=DateTime.Today
});
```

**EF Core 7**

EF Core 7 offers the same functionality too, using SqlQuery :

```
var rate=context.Database
    .SqlQuery<decimal>($@"SELECT Currency
        FROM KurTable
        WHERE SourceKur = {sourceCurrency}
            AND TargetKur = {targetCurrency}
            AND Date <= {targetDate}
        ORDER BY Date DESC")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This isn't a string interpolation operation. The formattable string is used to generate parameters and fill their values.

[SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.sqlquery?view=efcore-7.0) returns an IQueryable<> which means we could use `OrderByDescending` to specify the sort order too:

```
var rate=context.Database
    .SqlQuery<decimal>($@"SELECT Currency,Date
        FROM KurTable
        WHERE SourceKur = {sourceCurrency}
            AND TargetKur = {targetCurrency}
            AND Date <= {targetDate}")
    .OrderByDescending(c=>c.Date)
    .Select(c=>c.Currency)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

And, of course if the table was an *entity*, we could just write a LINQ query.

```
var rate=context.ExchangeRates
                .Where(xr=>xr.SourceCurrency==sourceCurrency &&
                           xr.TargetCurrency==targetCurrency &&
                           xr.Date <= targetDate)
                .OrderByDescending(xr=>xr.Date)
                .Select(xr=>xr.Currency)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Using a stored procedure**

A stored procedure that returns the latest exchange rate for a specific date would look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrencyAtDate]
    @sourceCurrencyId INT,
    @targetCurrencyId int,
    @targetDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 Currency
    FROM KurTable
    WHERE SourceKur = @soruceCurrencyId
        AND TargetKur = @targetCurrencyId
        AND Date <= @targetDate
    ORDER BY Date DESC
END
```

This can be called either with Dapper or EF Core 7:

```
var rate= con.ExecuteScalar<decimal>("GetCurrencyAtDate",
    new { 
        sourceCurrencyId =sourceCurrency,
        targetCurrencyId =targetCurrency,
        targetDate =DateTime.Today
    },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

In EF Core 7 :

```
var rate=context.Database
    .SqlQuery<decimal>($"exec GetCurrencyAtDate 
    @sourceCurrencyID={sourceCurrency}, 
    @targetCurrencyId= {targetCurrency}, 
    @targetDate = {targetDate}")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you for your all explanations. Let me learn more.

Comment: Very nicely explained!

Answer (score 1):

Just Declare Your Stored Procedure Parameters with NULL Default Value.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrencyAtDate]
@soruceCurrencyId int = NULL,
@targetCurrencyId int = NULL,
@year int = NULL ,
@month int = NULL,
@day int = NULL,
@result decimal OUTPUT
```